# Access contents of sub parameters in JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm having some trouble fully accessing contents of a JSON returned response.
What I'm working with looks like this:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": { 
                "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/66"
        },
        "fixtures": { 
                "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/66/fixtures"
        },
        "players": {
                "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/66/players"
        }
    },
    "name": "Manchester United FC",
    "shortName": "ManU",
    "squadMarketValue": "377,250,000 €",
    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/d/da/Manchester_United_FC.svg"
}
```

What I'm not fully understanding is how I can get hold of the contents inside "_links".
As of right now I'm having no problem reading the other variables name, shortname, squadMarketvalue and crestUrl.

This is my method for fetching the data:

```
public Container <Team> getTeam(String league) {
    String url = "http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/";
    String team = "/teams";

    url = url.concat(league);
    url = url.concat(team);

    String response = getData(url);

    Container <Team> teams = new Container<>();
    TeamContainer dataTeam = new Gson().fromJson(response, TeamContainer.class);

    for(Team t : dataTeam.getTeams()) {
        teams.add(new Team(t.getName(), t.getCode(), t.getShortName(),
                t.getSquadMarketValue(), t.getCrestUrl()));

    }
    return teams;
}
```

Comment: Huh? football-data doesn't have V2 API?

Comment: No problem. Any idea on my problem though?

Comment: I don't understand why you are for looping and iterating over each `Team` and reconstructing a new `Team`. That seems unnecessary. Also, is Team, TeamContainer your classes? If so can you show sample code for those classes?